# TSQL Update Column B with Column A's Value that is also being updated

Tags: t-sql

I am processing 155+ Million rows in a table and doing it in batches for performance and ran into a situation where the value in a column didn't get updated as expected.  I know I can solve it a couple of different ways but I wanted to see if someone knows how to do it in a single update statement.

Below is a test case:

```
DECLARE @TempIds TABLE (    
    ColA int,
    ColB int
) 

--seed the values for a test
INSERT INTO @TempIds (ColA,ColB) VALUES (1, 2)

--do the update
UPDATE @TempIds SET ColA = (3+5), ColB = (1-ColA) 

--see the results
SELECT * FROM @TempIds
```

The results of the above is:

```
ColA    ColB
8       0
```

Desired Outcome is

```
ColA    ColB
8       -7
```

The update statement is using the current value for ColA which is "1" when updating ColB instead of using the final value of ColA being "8".

I know that I can solve this by doing one of the following:

```
UPDATE @TempIds SET ColA = (3+5)
UPDATE @TempIds SET ColB = (1-ColA) 
    
--see the results
SELECT * FROM @TempIds
    
OR 
    
UPDATE @TempIds SET ColA = (3+5), ColB = 1-(3+5)
    
--see the results
SELECT * FROM @TempIds
```

Either one of the above will result in the following output:

```
ColA    ColB
8       -7
```

This is a simplified version as the actual query has a lot of computations and formulas to calculate the value for ColA.

I am trying to avoid two update statements or the need to repeat the formula for ColA in the ColB formula.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know this is probably a much simplified example. but will making `ColB` a computed column resolve your issue ?

Comment: @Squirrel In this case, making it a computed column would lead to performance issues as ColB is also used other queries as part of the where clause.  My understanding is this can lead to performance issues, especially when querying large tables.

Comment: A computed column can be persisted and indexed, so it may not be the performance hit you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Could you possibly make use of an Updatable CTE by first creating a new column A and then referencing it:

```
with updateme as (
    select *, (3+5) as NewA
    from @TempIds
)
update updateme set colA = NewA, colb = 1-NewA;

select * from @TempIds;
```

Comment: This definitely will work and I have used CTE many times.  The complexity of my situation would require at least 2 CTE's as my ColA and ColB example is really ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD and several depend on each other in a certain order.  The solution mentioned below from @sticky-bit also worked.  I have never used a variable at the same time of setting a column value in an update statement, but it actually worked.  I created 2 variables and was able to update all 4 columns correctly.  Thank you so much though for your suggestion as it was helpful in a different situation.

Answer (score 2):

There's the possibility to use a variable.

```
DECLARE @newcola integer;
UPDATE @tempids
       SET @newcola = cola = 3 + 5,
           colb = 1 - @newcola;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=045f65c9c13266e9aaf2f3046fb18d37)

Comment: I have never used a variable at the same time of setting a column value in an update statement, but it actually worked. I created 2 variables and was able to update all 4 columns correctly and each variable cascaded correctly.  Thank you as you saved me a ton of time.

Comment: @manrysj From [`update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "SET _@variable = column = expression_ sets the variable to the same value as the column. This differs from SET _@variable = column, column = expression_, which sets the variable to the pre-update value of the column."